# in memcmp can we use array instead of pointer

Tags: c

I came across the following line of code :

```
              memcmp(mac, (char []){0x01,0x00,0x5E}, 3)
```

Maybe it will work ; Is it alright to code memcmp in the above manner ? Thanks.

Comment: It's OK if you can assume C99 (or at least gcc). Don't try this with a C89 compiler though. (I haven't tried it but I doubt that this works with MSVC for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is alright. To declare an array anonymously like this, is known as "compound literals". It is a feature that was introduced in the C language with the C99 standard and will work with all compilers that follow the standard. It will not work with non-standard compilers like Visual C++.

You should however consider to declare it as `const char`, which would be more correct and may also result in better optimizations, since `const` might make it easier for the compiler/linker to place the array in static ROM instead of the stack.

Comment: Not just easier; the compiler is only permitted to create compound literals with static storage duration if they're const-qualified. Even if it can tell the data is constant, the compound literal is required to have an address unique to the invocation of the function (which matters in cases of recursion/reentrancy, for instance) as long as it's non-const-qualified.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will work, no problem, it's the same as:

```
char arr[] = {0x01,0x00,0x5E};
memcmp(mac, arr, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context, an array doesn't really differ in any regard from a pointer (keyword "array-to-pointer decay").

Since C lets you define temporary arrays in this fashion, you are allowed to use this notation to test a bunch of values that are known at compile time to be in your `mac` array.